# complex line copying&modifying on-the-fly with grep or sed

Tags: bash, sed, grep

Is there a way to do the followings with either grep, or sed: read each line of a file, and copy it twice and modify each copy:

Original line:

```
X Y Z
A B C
```

New lines:

```
Y M X
Y M Z
B M A
B M C
```

where X, Y, Z, M are all integers, and M is a fixed integer (i.e. 2) we inject while copying! I suppose a solution (if any) will be so complex that people (including me) will start bleeding after seeing it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -v M=2 '{print $2,M,$1; print $2,M,$3;}' file
Y 2 X
Y 2 Z
B 2 A
B 2 C
```

#### How it works

- `-v M=2`

  This defines the variable `M` to have value 2.
- `print $2,M,$1`

  This prints the second column, followed by `M`, followed by the first column.
- `print $2,M,$3`

  This prints the second column, followed by `M`, followed by the third column.

### Extended Version

Suppose that we want to handle an arbitrary number of columns in which we print all columns between first and last, followed by M, followed by the first, and then print all columns between first and last, followed by M, followed by the last.  In this case, use:

```
awk -v M=2 '{for (i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "%s ",$i; print M,$1; for (i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "%s ",$i; print M,$NF;}' file
```

As an example, consider this input file:

```
$ cat file2
X Y1 Y2 Z
A B1 B2 C
```

The above produces:

```
$ awk -v M=2 '{for (i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "%s ",$i; print M,$1; for (i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "%s ",$i; print M,$NF;}' file2
Y1 Y2 2 X
Y1 Y2 2 Z
B1 B2 2 A
B1 B2 2 C
```

The key change to the code is the addition of the following command:

```
for (i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "%s "
```

This command prints all columns from the `i=2`, which is the column *after* the first to `i=NF-1` which is the column *before* the last.  The code is otherwise similar.

Comment: Sweet! you are the best thing that has ever happened to me!

Comment: Can we copy arbitrary number of columns? Any number of columns between the first column and the last column for example? awk -v M=2 '{print $(ALLCOLUMNSBETWEENFIRSTANDLAST),M,$1; print $(ALLCOLUMNSBETWEENFIRSTANDLAST),M,$(NF-1);}' file

Comment: @user3639557 Yes, we can.  I added code for print-all-columns-between-first-and-last to the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sure; you can write:

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)/\2 M \1\n\2 M \3/'
```

Comment: You also need to replace `M` with some integer. You could easily do that with another sed command though: `sed 's/ M / 2 /g'`.

Comment: or `m=2; sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)/\2 '$m' \1\n\2 '$m' \3/' file`

Answer (score 1):

With bash builtin commands:

```
m=2; while read a b c; do echo "$b $m $a"; echo "$b $m $c"; done < file
```

Output:

```
Y 2 X
Y 2 Z
B 2 A
B 2 C
```